# CSS Precedence Issue

Tags: html, css

I have in my style.css the rule which applies to entire web site:

```
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;color:#E35B00;}
```

I have also in my button.css:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 0 2px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;   
    padding: .5em 1.5em .55em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em; 
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
.green {
    color: #e8f0de;
    border: solid 1px #538312;
    background: #64991e;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7db72f), to(#4e7d0e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7db72f,  #4e7d0e);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7db72f', endColorstr='#4e7d0e');
}
.green:hover {
    background: #538018;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6b9d28), to(#436b0c));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6b9d28,  #436b0c);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b9d28', endColorstr='#436b0c');
}
.green:active {
    color: #a9c08c;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4e7d0e), to(#7db72f));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4e7d0e,  #7db72f);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4e7d0e', endColorstr='#7db72f');
}
```

In my html page I have declared style.css before the button.css:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/button.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The code is:

```
<div>
<form action="dosomething.htm" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Option 1">
<a href="#" class="button green" onclick="callafunction()">Option 2</a>
</form>
</div>
```

The blue button (Option 1) has no problem with hovering because it is not an anchor.  However the green button (Option 2) when hover over "Option 2" it is turning to the color of a:hover which is `#E35B00` orange color instead of `#538018;` green color!

On the Firefox developer Rules console I am seeing the a:hover is below the green:hover.  Why is this the case?  I tried rearranging the order of the css but it's no use.  The a:hover takes over the green:hover. This is driving me nuts.  Your help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: color (text) is not the same like background so you overwrite the text-value and set the background-color. Define a background for both styles and it should work.

Comment: @DanielRuf can you post your suggestion as an answer so that I can see what you mean?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never specify what color you want the text to be when you hover on the `.green` button, so it defaults to `a:hover`. To fix this, you just have to add in the color of what the `.green` button to the CSS `.green:hover` rule.

The whole `.green:hover` CSS rule should look like this.

```
.green:hover {
    color: #e8f0de;
    background: #538018;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6b9d28), to(#436b0c));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6b9d28,  #436b0c);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b9d28', endColorstr='#436b0c');
}
```

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #E35B00;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0 2px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .5em 1.5em .55em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
.green {
  color: #e8f0de;
  border: solid 1px #538312;
  background: #64991e;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7db72f), to(#4e7d0e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7db72f, #4e7d0e);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7db72f', endColorstr='#4e7d0e');
}
.green:hover {
  color: #e8f0de;
  background: #538018;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6b9d28), to(#436b0c));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6b9d28, #436b0c);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b9d28', endColorstr='#436b0c');
}
.green:active {
  color: #a9c08c;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4e7d0e), to(#7db72f));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7d0e, #7db72f);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4e7d0e', endColorstr='#7db72f');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="dosomething.htm" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Option 1" />
    <a href="#" class="button green" onclick="callafunction()">Option 2</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to put `!important` after `color: #e8f0de` in the `.green` CSS rule. `!important` makes a property take precedence no matter what.

If you want to do this, then the first line of the `.green` rule should be.

```
color: #e8f0de !important;
```

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #E35B00;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0 2px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .5em 1.5em .55em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
.green {
  color: #e8f0de !important;
  border: solid 1px #538312;
  background: #64991e;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7db72f), to(#4e7d0e));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7db72f, #4e7d0e);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7db72f', endColorstr='#4e7d0e');
}
.green:hover {
  background: #538018;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6b9d28), to(#436b0c));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6b9d28, #436b0c);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b9d28', endColorstr='#436b0c');
}
.green:active {
  color: #a9c08c;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4e7d0e), to(#7db72f));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7d0e, #7db72f);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4e7d0e', endColorstr='#7db72f');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="dosomething.htm" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Option 1" />
    <a href="#" class="button green" onclick="callafunction()">Option 2</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: By changing the background to color, it will make the word which was originally white, becoming green.  It is not visible.  If you look at the [original design](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-buttons.html) the word should not change color when hovering over.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's working now  :)  It puzzled me why the [author's site](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-buttons.html) worked without declaring it?

Comment: Thanks.  I copied the code right out of the author's site.  He didn't use it.  His anchor was blue but somehow it didn't affect his buttons.